# Doctrine OCI8 charset behavior between php-cli and php-fpm

Tags: php, character-encoding, oracle-database, symfony

My Oracle database is in `ISO8859-1` (not by choice).

I'm struggling with segfault from `php-fpm` for a couple of days now. To dig out the source of it I've set two parallel environnements with the following `ENV` variable:

```
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15
```

Php version: 5.6.12

#### php-cli

The development server is started with:

```
php -S localhost:8081 web/app_dev.php
```

#### php-fpm

Pool configuration extract:

```
[www]
env[NLS_LANG] = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P15
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

#### Doctrine dbal

```
charset: null
```

Now, I'm requesting a `JSON` api with special characters:

- with `php-cli` `json_encode` errors `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` (seems to be a valid error, data is not in utf8)
- with `php-fpm` everything works but special characters are replaced (`é` becomes `e`) Why?

By trying to fix the `php-cli`, which seems more stable (lots of random 502 errors with `php-fpm`) I have two options:

- Tweaking `JsonResponse.php` to encode everything from ISO8859-1 to UTF-8 (ugly)
- Setting the client charset to `UTF8`

The second solution seems to be the one and the doctrine configuration is now:

```
charset: UTF8
```

- `php-cli` now works as expected and everything is wonderful!
- `php-fpm` fails with Oracle related errors:

> [2015-08-25 13:56:54] php.DEBUG: oci_connect(): OCIEnvNlsCreate()
>   failed. There is something wrong with your system - please check that
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes the directory with Oracle Instant Client
>   libraries
>
> [2015-08-25 13:56:54] php.DEBUG: oci_connect(): Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12715

Where ORA-12715 is "invalid character set specified".`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not the issue here.

What is going wrong here? Is `php-fpm` correct about those errors? 
How may I fix this to get the same behavior between `php-cli` and `php-fpm`?

Comment: You need to put on the php-fpm pool configuration file the env ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Indeed see my own answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649581/oracle-pdo-oci-charset-failing